# Can I put a link to a for-profit online course link in my profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I recently created a course (about a certain JavaScript framework) on an online learning website.  Can I include a link to this course in my profile in the "About Me" section?  Is this allowed? The course is not free.

More generally, what am I allowed to put in my profile?  Are there some guidelines written somewhere?

Comment: Please do! Having benefited from your excellent answers in the past, I would have been happy to find out that you'd created a more in-depth course I could consider buying. :)

Answer (score 61):

As I understand it, if it's legal and safe for work, you can put your heart's content over there.

All allowed:

- hire me;
- donate now;
- annoying GIFs;
- political declarations;
- project/corporate links;
- I'm awesome because "[...]";
- JavaScript/HTML apps and games;
- I'm waiting for you at my facebook.com/stackuser.

REFERENCES:

- [Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31504/185667)
- [Why is the f word still allowed in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31197/185667)
- [Is spam in the “about me” field a reason to worry?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105218/185667)

Comment: +1 because every bullet point is longer than the one before.

Comment: On the subject of _annoying GIFs_: Do check out my profile for an example of the ultimate annoying and useless GIF :-)

Comment: @JonasCz you were not lying about the annoying part!

Comment: …and if it's not safe for work, just add *(NSFW)* to your username :-)

Comment: @JonasCz Is the annoying part the mis-spelling of miscellaneous? ;)

Comment: Legal is sometimes incompatible with political declarations :-) Religious declarations are another commonly seen theme.

Comment: @JonasCz Wow, that's really incredible. Almost as annoying as `<marquee>`...

Comment: @JonasCz What programming language is `print("string");` valid in, anyway?

Comment: @cat Lua, for example.

Comment: @Kroltan Good catch, I haven't used Lua in a while. It's valid in Python, too, but the semicolon is superfluous.

Comment: @cat True, in both languages.

Comment: @cat, It's also valid in other languages if you have a `print(..)` method / function.

Comment: It is valid in PHP as well

Comment: @cat - Its valid in most languages, its just not a built-in method in lots of them

Comment: @Sayse That was my point: languages with builtin stdout writers named `print` that end statements with semicolons. Apparently PHP is a candidate.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩: Right, arrrrr! May you be touched by His Noodly Appendage!

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩  So true!!! Fair warning: check if your country allows #InsultDeludedDictator hashtags